# React OnAnimationEnd Issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making a simple notification service in React, and have encountered a very strange issue which I cannot find any mention of or solution to.

My component has an array of notification messages. Each "notification" has both a "onClick" and "onAnimationEnd" binding that call a function which will remove them from the array of notifications. The basic idea is that the notification will fade away (using a CSS animation) and then be removed, or allow the user to manually click on the notification to remove it.

The interesting bug is as follows.  If you add two notifications, the first one will trigger its onAnimationEnd and remove itself. The remaining notification will suddenly jump to the end of its css animation and never trigger its own onAnimationEnd.

Even more curiously if you add four notifications, exactly two of them will have the above bug, while the other two function properly.

It is also worth mentioning that if you create two notifications, and click on one two manually remove it, the remaining notification will act normally and trigger its own onAnimationEnd functionality.

Thus I am forced to conclude that some combination of looping through an array and the onAnimationEnd trigger is bugged somehow in react, unless someone can point out a solution to this problem.

**React Code**

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      notifications: []
    }
  }

  add = () => {
    this.setState({notifications: [...this.state.notifications, 'Test']})
  }

  remove = (notification) => {
    let notificationArray = this.state.notifications
    notificationArray.splice(notificationArray.indexOf(notification), 1)
    this.setState({notifications: notificationArray})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add Notification</button>
        <div className="notification-container">
        {this.state.notifications.map(
          (notification,i) => {
            return (
              <div onAnimationEnd={()=>this.remove(notification)} 
                   onClick={() => this.remove(notification)}
                   className="notification" 
                   key={i}>
                   {notification}
              </div>
            )
          }
        )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**CSS**

```
.notification-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.notification {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  user-select: none;
  animation: fade 7s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%,0);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-20px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
}
```

Working Codepen link
https://codepen.io/msorrentino/pen/xeVrwz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using an array index as your component key:

```
        {this.state.notifications.map(
          (notification,i) => {
            return (
              <div onAnimationEnd={()=>this.remove(notification)} 
                   onClick={() => this.remove(notification)}
                   className="notification" 
                   key={i}>
                   {notification}
              </div>
            )
          }
        )}
```

When you do this, React can't properly detect when your component is removed.  For example, by removing the item at index 0, and moving the item at index 1 into its place, React will think the item with key 0 has merely been modified rather than removed.  This can have various side-effects, such as what you're seeing.

Try using a unique identifier if you have one, otherwise use some kind of incrementing key.

To test this real fast in your codepen, change these bits (I don't actually recommend using your message as your key, of course):

```
add = () => {
    this.setState({notifications: [...this.state.notifications, Math.random().toString()]})
}

...

key={notification}
```

Array indexes should only be used as component keys as a last resort.

Comment: Dylan thank you for your reply. If this were the case however, why would the onClick version of removing a notification element work properly? They are essentially doing the exact same thing. onClick would remove the element, and cause the index key to get recalculated, but the animation continues to function in this case

Comment: It's hard to be 100% sure, because I'm not 100% sure how React optimizes things using keys, but imagine something like: (Spawn notification 0) -> (Spawn notification 1) -> (Early dismiss notification 0) -> (Notification 1 inherits 0's `onAnimationEnd` because React thinks it's actually 0).  Now imagine this scenario without manual dismissal: (0's `onAnimationEnd` fires) -> (1 inherits 0's `onAnimationend`, but the animation has already ended, so it will never fire).

Comment: If your notifications were more complex in their text, I guarantee odd things would start to happen with just the `onClick()`, they're just not noticeable right now since all your notifications are just 'test'.  You don't have to take my word for it though, give it a shot!

Comment: @mls3590712 Here, I thought of a way to demonstrate.  In your codepen, spawn 1 notification, wait ~4 seconds, then spawn a second notification.  Immediately after spawning the second notification, dismiss the first notification (the one on top).  The one remaining will immediately progress part way through the fading and disappear early.

Comment: I can confirm that your solution of a unique key does fix the problem. It is vexing to me that such odd behavior happened (exactly half didn't work, but the other half did). Thank you for your insight.